# JSP: simple IF condition not working

Tags: jsp

I am new on JSP. My  simple if condition is not working properly.

```
//row.getString("labels.above") is taken from database its value is "true"

< input type="radio" <% if(row.getString("labels.above")=="true"){ %><%="checked" %><% } %> />True
```

but it is not marking check on radio button.

this condition must be true. as
this:

```
 <%=row.getString("labels.above")%>:<%="true" %>
```

Output:

```
true:true
```

Comment: Avoid *Scriplet* as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For String comparison use `String#equals()` method instead of `==`

It should be

```
"true".equals(row.getString("labels.above"))
```

---

I suggest you to use [JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakc.html) or [Expression Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html) instead of `Scriplet` that is more easy to use and less error prone.

Answer (score 0):

[Don't compare strings in java using the `==` operator.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java/513839#513839)

The short story is that `==` will test to see if the two strings reference the exact same object, while the `.equals` method will test if the strings match character-for-character.  In almost all cases, you want to check using `.equals`